# how to wait rendering component till all data is gathert in Angular 2

Tags: angular, asynchronous, typescript

I tryed many things to get ngModel working in my edit page, but it gives me an error. The error occours beacause ngModel tries to get the data before it is loaden. See my code below.

ProductEditComponent

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Product } from './../shared/product.model';
import { ProductService } from './../shared/product.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'product-edit',
    template: require('./product-edit.component.html'),
    providers: [ProductService]
})

export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {
    product: Product;
    name2: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private productService: ProductService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        var test = this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this.productService.getProduct(+params['id']))
            .subscribe(product => this.product = product).closed;
            console.log(test);
        if (test['closed']) {
            this.name2 = true;
        }
    }

    goBack(): void {
        this.location.back();
    }

    onSave(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['product-edit', this.product]);
    }
}
```

ProducEdit HTML

```
<div class="product-edit">
    <h2>Edit: {{product?.name}}</h2>
    <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="name2">
        <label for="name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="name2" placeholder="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i wait till data is loaded and than render my component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only assume it's related to the product object not being instantiated. Use *ngIf like this. No need to initialize to null since null is 'falsy'

```
<div class="product-edit" *ngIf="product">
<h2>Edit: {{product?.name}}</h2>
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="name2">
    <label for="name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="name2" placeholder="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the router to preload the product data for you before it even instantiates the `ProductEditComponent`.

More specifically, you need to use a `Resolve` guard in the route declaration, e.g.:

```ts
{
  path: 'product/:productId',
  component: ProductEditComponent,
  resolve: { product: ProductResolver }
}
```

where `ProductResolver` is a custom service that will load the product with the id `productId`.

Check out the official doc, which contains a full example showing how to declare the route, how to implement the resolve, and how to retrieve the prefetched data inside a component: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#resolve-guard

Answer (score 1):

First initialize the product to null

```
product: Product = null;
```

Second add *ngIf to the html

```
<div class="product-edit" *ngIf="product != null">
    <h2>Edit: {{product.name}}</h2>
    <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="name2">
        <label for="name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="name2" placeholder="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *ngIf="!!product"